# How to install clpq library in swi-prolog

Tags: prolog, clpq

I am running `SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.2.3)` on Debian Stable Linux. 
I want to install `clpq` package for Constraint Logic Programming.

However, it does not seem to be there on querying with `pack_list` command:

```
?- pack_list(clpq).
% Contacting server at http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/query ... done
Warning: Unknown message: pack(search_no_matches(clpq))
true.
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to install anything. Just try:

```
?- use_module(library(clpq)).
```

You are using an *ancient* SWI-Prolog. Instructions on how to get something more up-to-date on Ubuntu (and probably Debian?):

http://www.swi-prolog.org/build/PPA.txt

Comment: Is it possible to use prolog code in python with other prolog interpreters e.g. `YAP` (available in Debian Linux repository)?

Comment: @rnso I don't know.